# Question about probability of sum of random number of random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, X_2,...$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with distribution $P(X_i = x) = p$ if $x=1$ and $P(X_i = x) = 1-p$ if $x=0$.  Let N be a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$, independent of the $X_i$'s.  Find $P(S_n = k)$ for $k=0,1,2,...$ where $Sn = X_1 + X_2,...$

I'm really not sure how to get started on this homework problem.  We have been doing a lot of stuff about conditional expectation and variance, and the laws of total probability and total expectation, but I'm really not sure how those tie into this question.  I understand that we know the probabilities for $X_i$ and for $N$, and we know that $E[S_n] = E[X]E[N]$.

Any help on how to find the probability of $S_n$ will be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Law of Total Probability is the relevant item. The probability that $S_N=k$ is the sum from $n=0$ to $\infty$ of $\Pr(N=n)\Pr(S_N=k|N=n)$. The conditional distribution is binomial, so we have formulas for all the needed components.

Comment: Thank you.  The only part I don't understand is why the conditional distribution is binomial.  As in - how would you calculate it?  I thought only the X distribution was binomial.  Also, what kind of answer would they be looking for in a question like this - could I leave the answer as the sum from n=0 to infinity once I plug in the formulas?

Comment: Would the formula for the conditional distribution just be ${n\choose x}(p)^x(1-p)^{n-x}$ ?

Comment: If $N=n$ then we have performed an experiment independently $n$ times, and the sum counts the number of successes. As to whether to simplify, that depends on what is expected. I think it should simplify, but I have not yet done the calculation. Certainly a lot of stuff in $k$ "comes out" of the sum, and the $n!$ of the binomial cancels the $n!$ in the Poisson formula.

Comment: Yes, the formula in your new comment gives the conditional distribution.

Comment: Another quick question for you.  In the next part of the homework, we are supposed to find $E[N | S_n = k]$.  I know that $E[N | S_n = k]$ is the sum from n=0 to infinity of $nP(N=n|S_n = k)$.  I also know to use Bayes' theorem, so $P(N=n|S_n = k) = \frac{P(S_n = k|N = n)P(N=n)}{P(S_n = k)}$.  However, the part I'm stuck with is that if we plug in the denominator from the first part of the question, won't everything cancel except for the n that is being multiplied to find expected value?  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20347/discussion-between-user114014-and-andre-nicolas).

Comment: I don't use chat. The sum simplifies **very** nicely.  You should get Poisson parameter $\lambda p$. If you run into trouble I can show the full calculation, have it basically typed, but would prefer if you got it yourself.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I clicked chat because of the recommendation by the site.  I would really appreciate you showing me the full calculation for $E[N|S_n = k|$ because I've been working on it but it always just seems to cancel before I even plug any of the formulas in

Comment: Though one can use the result of the calculation that I gave in the answer below, it really is a different problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Given** that $N=n$, the probability that $S_n=k$ is
$$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$
Thus by the Law of Total Probability,
$$\Pr(S_N=k)=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\Pr(N=n).$$ 
We know an explicit formula for the probability that $N=n$. Substituting we get
$$\Pr(S_N=k)=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}.$$
Change the index of summation, using $w=n-k$. Then  after some cancellation  our sum can be rewritten as
$$e^{-\lambda}\cdot \frac{1}{k!}\cdot p^k\lambda^k\sum_{w=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda(1-p))^w}{w!}.$$
We recognize the inner sum as $e^{\lambda(1-p)}$. Now a bit of manipulation yields 
$$e^{-\lambda p} \frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!},$$
a very nice expression!