# Probability question about sums of random variables and conditional expectation

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, X_2,...$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with distribution $P(X_i = x) = p$ if $x=1$ and $P(X_i = x) = 1-p$ if $x=0$.  Let N be a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$, independent of the $X_i$'s.

First I found $P(S_n = k)$ for $k=0,1,2,...$ where $Sn = X_1 + X_2,...$ by using the law of total probability with help [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109783/question-about-probability-of-sum-of-random-number-of-random-variables#)

$$\Pr(S_N=k)=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\Pr(N=n).$$ 
We know an explicit formula for the probability that $N=n$. Substituting we get
$$\Pr(S_N=k)=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}.$$
Change the index of summation, using $w=n-k$. Then  after some cancellation  our sum can be rewritten as
$$e^{-\lambda}\cdot \frac{1}{k!}\cdot p^k\lambda^k\sum_{w=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda(1-p))^w}{w!}.$$
We recognize the inner sum as $e^{\lambda(1-p)}$. Now a bit of manipulation yields 
$$e^{-\lambda p} \frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!},$$

That's all fine.  But in the next part of the homework, we are supposed to find $E[N|Sn=k]$. I know that $E[N|Sn=k]$ is the sum from $n=0$ to $\infty$ of $nP(N=n|Sn=k)$. I also know to use Bayes' theorem, so $$P(N=n|Sn=k)=\frac{P(Sn=k|N=n)P(N=n)}{P(Sn=k)}$$ However, the part I'm stuck with is that if we plug in the denominator from the first part of the question, won't everything cancel except for the n that is being multiplied to find expected value? That doesn't seem right.